# bitcoin-cli getinfo error code: -28

Tags: bitcoin-cli

OSX Sierra

it seems all the other command bitcoin-cli working on my Mac,
except,

**bitcoin-cli getinfo** only always returns an error.

> $ bitcoin-cli getinfo 
>   error code: -28
>   error message:
>   Rewinding blocks...

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 4):

Wait a few minutes and the error will be gone.

The [source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/62f2d769e45043c1f262ed45babb70fe237ad2bb/src/rpc/protocol.h#L30) defines error 28 as

> Client still warming up

Comment: thank you for reply. After waiting 20 minutes, message was changed into "error code: -32601
error message:
Method not found"

Comment: That's because `getinfo` was removed. It's marked as deprecated with a warning in 0.15, but apparently you're running master (which will become 0.16, with `getinfo` removed).

Comment: You should use `getwalletinfo`, `getblockchaininfo`, `getpeerinfo`, `getnetworkinfo`, ... to request more specific information.

Comment: I tried these commands you showed then I got return! Thank you!

Comment: In case these commands also return an error 28, you can follow the progress by tailing the debug log: `tail -f debug.log`

Answer (score 3):

use `bitcoin-cli -getinfo` instead of `getinfo`